# What is the preferred translation of "A leader serves" into Latin?

Tags: sentence-translation, motto

*Dux servit*? *Dux ministrat*? Something else? I would like to use this as a motto for a club.

I am using leader in the sense of "Someone in a leadership position serves" or "One of the characteristics of a leader is that he serves the people around him".

Comment: Do you want a translation or it may also be a quote? Mottos frequently (preferently?) are citations or paraphrasing of ancient works.

Comment: Thank Joonas for your help, and Rafael for the thoughtful question. I'm grateful for a translation, although an ancient citation would give it added credence.

Comment: @BobSylvain BTW among your translations, I like _dux ministrat_. You may also want some other word for leader (a _dux_ is also an army general, e.g. _magnus_, _primus [inter pares]_)

Answer (score 5):

Caveat: *you may or may not feel comfortable with a motto with religious background, but the concept we have today of a leader as a servant has had a strong influence from Christianity, so personally I don't see any harm in using it even if you/your club is not religious at all. Moreover, there is precedent of this specific motto being used by non-religious groups*

I propose:

> **Non ministrari sed ministrare** ([Mt 20:28](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mateo%2020%3A28&version=VULGATE))

Literally means [I have come] *not to be served but to serve*. The context is Jesus explaining his disciples that *anyone who wants to become great among you must be* [each other's] *servant* (Mt 20:26.) This is the base of the western concept of exerting leadership/power by serving.

It has been the motto of a number of educational institutions from different, Christian and non-Christian backgrounds (e.g. [1](http://www.cmisabel.com/Saludo.aspx), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenox_School_for_Boys), [3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queens_University_of_Charlotte), [4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wellesley_College)) and at least one [bishop](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolfo_Rodriguez_Vidal) (presumably more.)

Side comments:

1. In Spanish it is common to call a country's President *Primer Mandatario* (something in the line of *first mandatary/trustee*, first one being mandated, even at the point that *mandatario* has kind of lost its original meaning and is at times translated as *leader*.)
2. Most Popes, as well as some Western civil rulers have considered themselves *servants* at the point of coining and using the title *servus servorum Dei* ([servant of the servants of God](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servant_of_the_servants_of_God).) Of course some have used the title just as a formality but also some have trully meant it.

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion is ***dux servit ductis***, "leader serves those (s)he leads".
A mere *dux servit* is also fine, but adding the people being served and lead gives it more nuance.
And it sounds better if you ask me.

In a similar spirit, you could say ***ducere est servire***, "to lead is to serve".

Answer (score 3):

**Dux servit** was the first thought that came to my (non-expert) mind.

Less terse but still epigrammatic:

> Etiam servit qui ducit.

The reversed word order might give it the kind of poignancy that you're looking for.